# Custom Loss function Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement my own custom loss function in Keras for an RNN (LSTM). Here is my code.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\\Users\\skaul\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\Lib\\site-packages")

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import keras.backend as K

timesteps = 10
data_dim = 5
timesteps = 10
num_classes = 2

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ytrue = K.argmax(y_true, axis = 1) 
    ypred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1)

    true1 = ytrue
    pred1 = ypred
    pred0 = ypred - K.cast(K.variable(1),dtype = 'int64')
    pred0 = pred0 * K.cast(K.variable(-1),dtype = 'int64')
    tp = K.sum(true1*pred1) #true positives
    fn = K.sum(true1*pred0) #false negatives

    return K.cast(fn/tp,dtype = 'float32')


model.compile(loss = custom_loss,
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))

# Generate dummy validation data
x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

y_a = np.random.random(y_train.shape)
y_b = np.random.random(y_train.shape)

out1 = K.eval(custom_loss(K.variable(y_a), K.variable(y_b)))
print(out1)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0551e4a8e8ed> in <module>()
     52 print(out1)
     53 
---> 54 model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    868                               class_weight=class_weight,
    869                               sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 870                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    871 
    872     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1488         else:
   1489             ins = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1490         self._make_train_function()
   1491         f = self.train_function
   1492 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _make_train_function(self)
   1012                 self._collected_trainable_weights,
   1013                 self.constraints,
-> 1014                 self.total_loss)
   1015             updates = self.updates + training_updates
   1016             # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py in get_updates(self, params, constraints, loss)
    420 
    421         for p, g, m, v in zip(params, grads, ms, vs):
--> 422             m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
    423             v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(g)
    424             p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)

c:\users\skaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    827       if not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    828         try:
--> 829           y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
    830         except TypeError:
    831           # If the RHS is not a tensor, it might be a tensor aware object

c:\users\skaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    674       name=name,
    675       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 676       as_ref=False)
    677 
    678 

c:\users\skaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype)
    739 
    740         if ret is None:
--> 741           ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    742 
    743         if ret is NotImplemented:

c:\users\skaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    111                                          as_ref=False):
    112   _ = as_ref
--> 113   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    114 
    115 

c:\users\skaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    100   tensor_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue()
    101   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
--> 102       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    103   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    104   const_tensor = g.create_op(

c:\users\skaul\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    362   else:
    363     if values is None:
--> 364       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    365     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    366     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

This leads me to believe that my loss function is returning a 'None' value, however, my code outputs `0.941634`

before displaying the error shown above. This comes from the statement print(out1) which tests the loss function outside of the RNN. Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Comment: I can't figure out the problem, but something is fishy about pred1 and pred0. Pred1 will always be 1 and Pred0 will always be 0. (You summed the values before, and summing a 'softmax' result will always bring 1, that means, ytrue and ypred are made of ones.).

Comment: But you could try without the cast methods (it will bring the result anyway, perhaps with a bigger precision error if the float64 part is important to you)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for catching that - I'm now using argmax instead of sum to generate ytrue ypred. I believe keras expects a float32 output from the loss function which is why I'm casting there (I get an error if I don't). I am still getting the None values error.

Comment: Is this your complete code? You could update it with your changes :)

Comment: Ok, I tested your code, and it simply runs. Surely the problem is somwhere you're not showing.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry new to Stack Overflow, put the revised code full error in the original post. I have to add the correct path so it finds keras (import sys etc).  Maybe my error has to do with that?

Comment: @Daniel Just ran the code on a colleagues computer. He didn't botch the installation of keras/tensorflow so he doesn't need the import sys and path insertion yet he still gets the 'None values not supported' error.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem in this code. Copied and pasted it exactly as it is (without the `sys`). What is your keras version? I'm using theano backend, but I really do not believe it makes any difference, I'll try later at home with tensorflow. I had quite a few problems using Conda. I simply gave it up, uninstalled everything and installed a regular version of everything: mkl, mingw, python 3.5, numpy/scipy, tensorflow(or theano) and keras.

Comment: @Daniel I'm using keras 2.0.2

Comment: Update: at home, with tensorflow I get the same error as you, but I still can't understand why....

Comment: @Daniel Oh well. Thanks for your help. I guess I will try theano backend

Comment: check out the answer to this similar question. I can't verify the answer, but I haven't had any luck with the argmax function for my custom loss function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762881/custom-loss-function-implementation-issue-in-keras

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.Print(z,[z]) (z is the your variable) to print all the variables in your custom loss,before the return statement.Then you will know what values they take before the final return statement is executed.The problem will be clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not recommend using `fn/tp` as the loss function because it can lead to NaN value if tp = 0. So, I would suggest to just use your custom loss function as evaluation metrics to be monitored.

```
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy', custom_loss])
```

Second, I couldn't reproduce your error code. So, I am not sure whether this idea could solve your issue. Try to replace the way you calculate tp and fn by using tensorflow logical and reduce_sum functions.

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ytrue = K.argmax(y_true, axis = 1) 
    ypred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1)

    ypred_bool = tf.equal(ypred > 0, True)
    ytrue_bool = tf.equal(ytrue > 0, True) 
    
    tp = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(ypred_bool, ytrue_bool),dtype=tf.float32),axis=0) # true positives
    fn = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(tf.logical_not(ypred_bool), ytrue_bool),dtype=tf.float32),axis=0) # false negatives
    
    return K.cast(fn/tp,dtype = 'float32')
```